# how does selenium or appium do screenshot on iOS or android

Tags: selenium, appium

Could someone point me to the file that implements screenshot function on iOS? (or Android is OK)
We are trying to modify this behavior for our own needs, but I need a place to start.
I searched the git hub repo but could not determine where should I start.

Thanks,
J-

Answer (score 1):

Selenium implements the function, so you could modify their implementation of it.

**[Here's a gist of how to get and save the screenshot as a file](https://gist.github.com/JessicaSachs/7f3ab982eb65900c5159)**.

The better way is probably to put a wrapper around `save_screenshot` and do whatever you need to do with the image at that point.

Comment: Good info. One up. But I was asking how to change the "implementation" of the method, not how to wrap around it. Here is how I changed the code to use png format in stead of tiff format for Appium-for-Mac server side code. https://github.com/appium/appium-for-mac/commit/5e18352bd9629ced108c8d0a86577289ce23b97a

Comment: This takes the screen shot of the current viewport .. Can anything be done to take the screen shot of the entire page ?

Comment: viewport? show me what it is taking versus what you would like.